# Any one have experience using SwiftMailer? worked on Bluehost but not siteground

Tags: swiftmailer

Looking for someone that has experienced a similar issue using SwiftMailer. I had an application built on my Bluehost server that sent emails. Worked great, no issues. I have since moved this application(php/mysql) over to Siteground server. Same PHP version, same SwiftMailer version. But now it no longer sends emails. Its been a while since I have had to look at this section of the code so I am a bit lost as to where to even start. But it seems I must be missing some sort of configuration setting or some sort of server setting.

Code is below. Any thoughts,suggestions?

```
enter code here

$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($server,$port,$encryption)
->setUsername($user)
->setPassword($psw)
;

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport  

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create the message  
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

// Give the message a subject  
->setSubject($this->subject)

// Set the From address with an associative array  
->setFrom(array($this->from_email => $this->from_email))

// Give it a body  
->setBody($this->body);

$eml = new EmailAddressValidator; 

// Load to  
$array = array();
if (count($this->to_email)) {   
foreach ($this->to_email as $key => $value) {
if ($eml->check_email_address($value)) $array[strval($value)] = 
strval($value); 
}  
if (count($array)) $message->setTo($array);
}
// Load cc  
$array = array();  
if (count($this->cc_email)) {   
foreach ($this->cc_email as $key => $value) {
if ($eml->check_email_address($value)) $array[strval($value)] = 
strval($value); 
}
if (count($array)) $message->setCc($array);
}
$mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: Are you using you own SMTP or 3rd party SMTP like GMail?

Comment: I am using SMTP , I have a email address setup on Siteground that I am using to send through.

Comment: Can you test the SMTP configuration from your own PC (eg, sending email using Outlook/Thunderbird), and then try setup your app to use fake SMTP server like mailtrap? This could be a problem in the SMTP refusing connection from Siteground